# Statically link framework to an Xcode command line tool

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, frameworks

I am a mac user running 10.10.5 Yosemite and Xcode 6.3.2. In Documents there is a folder (generated by a command line tool project written in C++) called 'Game' with this structure:

```
Game:

     Game.xcodeproj (my project)

     Game:
          main.cpp (my c++ source)

     Build:
          Products:
                  Debug:
                        Game (an executable)
                        SDL2.framework (a development library)
```

I want to link to the SDL2.framework in Build/Products/Debug in such a way that it will run on any Mac, from this specific folder.

I have performed these steps:

I dragged SDL2.framework from Build/Products/Debug into my Project Navigator. I unchecked 'copy if needed.'

This automatically added the 'Link Binary with Libraries' build phase in which SDL2.framework is included.

SDL2.framework is referenced relative to group- in 'Build/Products/Debug/SDL2.framework,' as desired.

In my main.cpp I write:

```
 # include "SDL2/SDL.h"
```

The generated executable runs on my machine *no matter where the 'Game' folder highest in the hierarchy is.*

My project is **not** referencing the SDL2.framework in /Library/Frameworks. I can change the name of the SDL2.framework there and the program still runs. This suggests it is taking it from /Build/Products/Debug as I want it to.

However, when I take this whole folder onto a mac identical to mine the executable runs, but fails with this error:

```
  Last login: Sat Mar 26 11:32:08 on ttys002
  [~/ 1> /Volumes/NO\ NAME/Game/Build/Products/Debug/Game ; exit;
  dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: /Volumes/NO NAME/Game/Build/Products/Debug/Game
  Reason: image not found
  Trace/BPT trap
  logout

  [Process completed]
```

Having spent hours searching for a solution, I am dumbfounded. What am I doing wrong?